# Как настроить CLion на запуск ncurses внутри ide?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, ncurses

Я так понимаю, нужно настроить `g++` с аргументом `-lncurses`. Но не могу понять как сделать это в `JetBrains CLion`

---

В общем я добавил в конец `CMakeLists.txt`

> link_directories(/usr/include/)
>   target_link_libraries(myprogramname ncurses)

Теперь ошибка

> Error opening terminal: unknown.
>   Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Добавьте нужный аргумент в вашу CMake конфигурацию. Если очень надо через IDE, то в настройках в разделе CMake можно указать параметры.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду слинковать исполняемый файл с библиотекой ncurses? Если так, то через cmake.

Comment: А где именно параметры `cmake` указываются? В `Cmake options`? Я уже пробовал указывать `-lncurses` ошибки при компиляции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В CMake есть механизм поиска модулей. В числе стандартных есть [FindCurses](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCurses.html):

```
set(CURSES_NEED_NCURSES TRUE)
find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
if (CURSES_FOUND AND CURSES_HAVE_NCURSES_H)
  include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})
  target_link_libraries (target ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Comment: на предпоследней строке `Cannot specify link libraries for target "curses" which is not built by  this project.`

Comment: Вместо `target` поставьте наименование вашей цели

Comment: Сделал. Построение успешно. Но все равно не запускается. Ошибку я уже запостил в вопросе

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос и к Cmake и сборке приложения не относится.

Comment: "терминал", который встроен в clion не поддерживает подобного. Настраивайте, что бы оно запускало тот же xterm или запускайте ручками с терминала.

Answer (score 1):

В CMakeLists.txt после строчки `add_executable` добавить:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ncurses)
```

Компилироваться будет, но работать во встроенном терминале CLion код, использующий ncurses.h, не будет:

> Error opening terminal: unknown.